# Group data by multiply keys, sum and count for different keys in RamdaJS

Tags: javascript, group-by, ramda.js

I have an array of data that looks something like this

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "date":"2022-02-10",
         "date_ts":1644440400,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"d0q2",
         "sub3":"",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":8531.94,
         "sms_count":3102,
         "payout":29750.0,
         "net_margin":21218.06
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-10",
         "date_ts":1644440400,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"d0q1",
         "sub3":"data_check",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":5499.16,
         "sms_count":1999,
         "payout":12885.0,
         "net_margin":7385.84
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-10",
         "date_ts":1644440400,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"d1q1",
         "sub3":"vitrina",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":8994.3,
         "sms_count":3270,
         "payout":12748.0,
         "net_margin":3753.7
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-10",
         "date_ts":1644440400,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"d0q1",
         "sub3":"webbdata_check",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":4529.32,
         "sms_count":1647,
         "payout":14280.0,
         "net_margin":9750.68
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-10",
         "date_ts":1644440400,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"d0q3",
         "sub3":"",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":8537.82,
         "sms_count":3104,
         "payout":7140.0,
         "net_margin":-1397.82
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-10",
         "date_ts":1644440400,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"d1q2",
         "sub3":"bounce",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":2559.94,
         "sms_count":930,
         "payout":4707.0,
         "net_margin":2147.06
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-10",
         "date_ts":1644440400,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"d0q1",
         "sub3":"random",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":8476.62,
         "sms_count":3082,
         "payout":50616.0,
         "net_margin":42139.38
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-10",
         "date_ts":1644440400,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"d0q1",
         "sub3":"mondata_check",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":3745.6,
         "sms_count":1362,
         "payout":28000.0,
         "net_margin":24254.4
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-10",
         "date_ts":1644440400,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"d1q1",
         "sub3":"mondata_check",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":3894.98,
         "sms_count":1416,
         "payout":4000.0,
         "net_margin":105.02
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-10",
         "date_ts":1644440400,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"d0q1",
         "sub3":"kadata_check",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":3025.92,
         "sms_count":1100,
         "payout":0,
         "net_margin":-3025.92
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-10",
         "date_ts":1644440400,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"ppp",
         "sub2":"",
         "sub3":"",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":0,
         "sms_count":0,
         "payout":49400.0,
         "net_margin":49400.0
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-10",
         "date_ts":1644440400,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"bot",
         "sub2":"offers_list",
         "sub3":"",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":0,
         "sms_count":0,
         "payout":4000.0,
         "net_margin":4000.0
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-10",
         "date_ts":1644440400,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"bot",
         "sub3":"vitrina",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":0,
         "sms_count":0,
         "payout":225.0,
         "net_margin":225.0
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-11",
         "date_ts":1644526800,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"d0q1",
         "sub3":"random",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":7817.72,
         "sms_count":2842,
         "payout":37237.0,
         "net_margin":29419.28
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-11",
         "date_ts":1644526800,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"d1q1",
         "sub3":"mondata_check",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":3735.98,
         "sms_count":1358,
         "payout":0,
         "net_margin":-3735.98
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-11",
         "date_ts":1644526800,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"d1q1",
         "sub3":"vitrina",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":8381.16,
         "sms_count":3047,
         "payout":9120.0,
         "net_margin":738.84
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-11",
         "date_ts":1644526800,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"d0q1",
         "sub3":"webbdata_check",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":4255.14,
         "sms_count":1547,
         "payout":14280.0,
         "net_margin":10024.86
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-11",
         "date_ts":1644526800,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"d0q2",
         "sub3":"",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":7744.36,
         "sms_count":2816,
         "payout":19125.0,
         "net_margin":11380.64
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-11",
         "date_ts":1644526800,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"d0q1",
         "sub3":"mondata_check",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":3349.56,
         "sms_count":1218,
         "payout":36000.0,
         "net_margin":32650.44
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-11",
         "date_ts":1644526800,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"d0q1",
         "sub3":"data_check",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":5051.06,
         "sms_count":1836,
         "payout":15895.0,
         "net_margin":10843.94
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-11",
         "date_ts":1644526800,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"d0q3",
         "sub3":"",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":7701.2,
         "sms_count":2800,
         "payout":7140.0,
         "net_margin":-561.2
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-11",
         "date_ts":1644526800,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"d0q1",
         "sub3":"kadata_check",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":2885.4,
         "sms_count":1049,
         "payout":0,
         "net_margin":-2885.4
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-11",
         "date_ts":1644526800,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"d1q2",
         "sub3":"bounce",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":2123.72,
         "sms_count":772,
         "payout":8268.0,
         "net_margin":6144.28
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-11",
         "date_ts":1644526800,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"ppp",
         "sub2":"",
         "sub3":"",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":0,
         "sms_count":0,
         "payout":45600.0,
         "net_margin":45600.0
      },
      {
         "date":"2022-02-11",
         "date_ts":1644526800,
         "month":2,
         "week":6,
         "sub1":"sm",
         "sub2":"bot",
         "sub3":"vitrina",
         "sub4":"",
         "cost":0,
         "sms_count":0,
         "payout":3055.0,
         "net_margin":3055.0
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to group data by 2 (or more) parameters (in this case by **sub1** and **sub2**) and calculate the sum for the fields **payout** and **cost** and get count for the field **sms_count** and output only these values within groups. For example...

```
{
   "sm":{
      "d0q3":[
         {
            "date":"2022-02-03",
            "cost":8230.84,
            "sms_count":2993,
            "payout":11900
         },
         {
            "date":"2022-02-03",
            "cost":8230.84,
            "sms_count":2993,
            "payout":11900
         }
      ],
      "d1q1":[
         {
            "date":"2022-02-03",
            "cost":4043.29,
            "sms_count":1470,
            "payout":0
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I tried the following code, but it outputs all values and does not do counts

```
const groupAndSumMultipleParams = R.pipe(
        R.groupBy(R.prop('sub1')),
        R.map(R.groupBy(R.prop('sub2'))),
        R.values,
        R.map(R.reduce(
            R.mergeWith(R.ifElse(R.is(Number), R.add, R.identity)),
            {}
        ))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

To get to your expected result, you don't need to use `R.values` (you want an object, and not an array), and you'll need to map twice (two groupings) before reducing to a single object. In addition, you might want to use `R.pick` to remove redundant properties:

```js
const { pipe, pick, groupBy, prop, map, reduce, mergeWith, ifElse, is, add, identity } = R

const groupAndSumMultipleParams = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('sub1')),
  map(groupBy(prop('sub2'))),
  map(map(reduce(mergeWith(ifElse(is(Number), add, identity)), {}))),
  map(map(pick(['date', 'cost', 'sms_count', 'payout']))) // if you want to keep only certain properties
)

const obj = {"data":[{"date":"2022-02-10","date_ts":1644440400,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"d0q2","sub3":"","sub4":"","cost":8531.94,"sms_count":3102,"payout":29750,"net_margin":21218.06},{"date":"2022-02-10","date_ts":1644440400,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"d0q1","sub3":"data_check","sub4":"","cost":5499.16,"sms_count":1999,"payout":12885,"net_margin":7385.84},{"date":"2022-02-10","date_ts":1644440400,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"d1q1","sub3":"vitrina","sub4":"","cost":8994.3,"sms_count":3270,"payout":12748,"net_margin":3753.7},{"date":"2022-02-10","date_ts":1644440400,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"d0q1","sub3":"webbdata_check","sub4":"","cost":4529.32,"sms_count":1647,"payout":14280,"net_margin":9750.68},{"date":"2022-02-10","date_ts":1644440400,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"d0q3","sub3":"","sub4":"","cost":8537.82,"sms_count":3104,"payout":7140,"net_margin":-1397.82},{"date":"2022-02-10","date_ts":1644440400,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"d1q2","sub3":"bounce","sub4":"","cost":2559.94,"sms_count":930,"payout":4707,"net_margin":2147.06},{"date":"2022-02-10","date_ts":1644440400,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"d0q1","sub3":"random","sub4":"","cost":8476.62,"sms_count":3082,"payout":50616,"net_margin":42139.38},{"date":"2022-02-10","date_ts":1644440400,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"d0q1","sub3":"mondata_check","sub4":"","cost":3745.6,"sms_count":1362,"payout":28000,"net_margin":24254.4},{"date":"2022-02-10","date_ts":1644440400,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"d1q1","sub3":"mondata_check","sub4":"","cost":3894.98,"sms_count":1416,"payout":4000,"net_margin":105.02},{"date":"2022-02-10","date_ts":1644440400,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"d0q1","sub3":"kadata_check","sub4":"","cost":3025.92,"sms_count":1100,"payout":0,"net_margin":-3025.92},{"date":"2022-02-10","date_ts":1644440400,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"ppp","sub2":"","sub3":"","sub4":"","cost":0,"sms_count":0,"payout":49400,"net_margin":49400},{"date":"2022-02-10","date_ts":1644440400,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"bot","sub2":"offers_list","sub3":"","sub4":"","cost":0,"sms_count":0,"payout":4000,"net_margin":4000},{"date":"2022-02-10","date_ts":1644440400,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"bot","sub3":"vitrina","sub4":"","cost":0,"sms_count":0,"payout":225,"net_margin":225},{"date":"2022-02-11","date_ts":1644526800,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"d0q1","sub3":"random","sub4":"","cost":7817.72,"sms_count":2842,"payout":37237,"net_margin":29419.28},{"date":"2022-02-11","date_ts":1644526800,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"d1q1","sub3":"mondata_check","sub4":"","cost":3735.98,"sms_count":1358,"payout":0,"net_margin":-3735.98},{"date":"2022-02-11","date_ts":1644526800,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"d1q1","sub3":"vitrina","sub4":"","cost":8381.16,"sms_count":3047,"payout":9120,"net_margin":738.84},{"date":"2022-02-11","date_ts":1644526800,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"d0q1","sub3":"webbdata_check","sub4":"","cost":4255.14,"sms_count":1547,"payout":14280,"net_margin":10024.86},{"date":"2022-02-11","date_ts":1644526800,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"d0q2","sub3":"","sub4":"","cost":7744.36,"sms_count":2816,"payout":19125,"net_margin":11380.64},{"date":"2022-02-11","date_ts":1644526800,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"d0q1","sub3":"mondata_check","sub4":"","cost":3349.56,"sms_count":1218,"payout":36000,"net_margin":32650.44},{"date":"2022-02-11","date_ts":1644526800,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"d0q1","sub3":"data_check","sub4":"","cost":5051.06,"sms_count":1836,"payout":15895,"net_margin":10843.94},{"date":"2022-02-11","date_ts":1644526800,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"d0q3","sub3":"","sub4":"","cost":7701.2,"sms_count":2800,"payout":7140,"net_margin":-561.2},{"date":"2022-02-11","date_ts":1644526800,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"d0q1","sub3":"kadata_check","sub4":"","cost":2885.4,"sms_count":1049,"payout":0,"net_margin":-2885.4},{"date":"2022-02-11","date_ts":1644526800,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"d1q2","sub3":"bounce","sub4":"","cost":2123.72,"sms_count":772,"payout":8268,"net_margin":6144.28},{"date":"2022-02-11","date_ts":1644526800,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"ppp","sub2":"","sub3":"","sub4":"","cost":0,"sms_count":0,"payout":45600,"net_margin":45600},{"date":"2022-02-11","date_ts":1644526800,"month":2,"week":6,"sub1":"sm","sub2":"bot","sub3":"vitrina","sub4":"","cost":0,"sms_count":0,"payout":3055,"net_margin":3055}]}

const result = groupAndSumMultipleParams(obj.data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you want the keys you choose to group upon to be dynamic.  If that's the case, then something like this might work:

```js
const restructure = ([k, ...ks], fn) => (xs) =>
  (ks .length > 0 ? map (restructure (ks, fn)) : map (fn)) (groupBy (prop (k)) (xs))

const convert = restructure (['sub1', 'sub2'], applySpec ({
  date: pipe (head, prop ('date')),  // What if the dates are different?
  cost: pipe (pluck ('cost'), sum),
  sms_count: pipe (pluck ('sms_count'), sum),
  payout: pipe (pluck ('payout'), sum)
}))

const input = {data: [{date: "2022-02-10", date_ts: 1644440400, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "d0q2", sub3: "", sub4: "", cost: 8531.94, sms_count: 3102, payout: 29750, net_margin: 21218.06}, {date: "2022-02-10", date_ts: 1644440400, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "d0q1", sub3: "data_check", sub4: "", cost: 5499.16, sms_count: 1999, payout: 12885, net_margin: 7385.84}, {date: "2022-02-10", date_ts: 1644440400, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "d1q1", sub3: "vitrina", sub4: "", cost: 8994.3, sms_count: 3270, payout: 12748, net_margin: 3753.7}, {date: "2022-02-10", date_ts: 1644440400, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "d0q1", sub3: "webbdata_check", sub4: "", cost: 4529.32, sms_count: 1647, payout: 14280, net_margin: 9750.68}, {date: "2022-02-10", date_ts: 1644440400, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "d0q3", sub3: "", sub4: "", cost: 8537.82, sms_count: 3104, payout: 7140, net_margin: -1397.82}, {date: "2022-02-10", date_ts: 1644440400, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "d1q2", sub3: "bounce", sub4: "", cost: 2559.94, sms_count: 930, payout: 4707, net_margin: 2147.06}, {date: "2022-02-10", date_ts: 1644440400, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "d0q1", sub3: "random", sub4: "", cost: 8476.62, sms_count: 3082, payout: 50616, net_margin: 42139.38}, {date: "2022-02-10", date_ts: 1644440400, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "d0q1", sub3: "mondata_check", sub4: "", cost: 3745.6, sms_count: 1362, payout: 28e3, net_margin: 24254.4}, {date: "2022-02-10", date_ts: 1644440400, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "d1q1", sub3: "mondata_check", sub4: "", cost: 3894.98, sms_count: 1416, payout: 4e3, net_margin: 105.02}, {date: "2022-02-10", date_ts: 1644440400, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "d0q1", sub3: "kadata_check", sub4: "", cost: 3025.92, sms_count: 1100, payout: 0, net_margin: -3025.92}, {date: "2022-02-10", date_ts: 1644440400, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "ppp", sub2: "", sub3: "", sub4: "", cost: 0, sms_count: 0, payout: 49400, net_margin: 49400}, {date: "2022-02-10", date_ts: 1644440400, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "bot", sub2: "offers_list", sub3: "", sub4: "", cost: 0, sms_count: 0, payout: 4e3, net_margin: 4e3}, {date: "2022-02-10", date_ts: 1644440400, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "bot", sub3: "vitrina", sub4: "", cost: 0, sms_count: 0, payout: 225, net_margin: 225}, {date: "2022-02-11", date_ts: 1644526800, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "d0q1", sub3: "random", sub4: "", cost: 7817.72, sms_count: 2842, payout: 37237, net_margin: 29419.28}, {date: "2022-02-11", date_ts: 1644526800, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "d1q1", sub3: "mondata_check", sub4: "", cost: 3735.98, sms_count: 1358, payout: 0, net_margin: -3735.98}, {date: "2022-02-11", date_ts: 1644526800, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "d1q1", sub3: "vitrina", sub4: "", cost: 8381.16, sms_count: 3047, payout: 9120, net_margin: 738.84}, {date: "2022-02-11", date_ts: 1644526800, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "d0q1", sub3: "webbdata_check", sub4: "", cost: 4255.14, sms_count: 1547, payout: 14280, net_margin: 10024.86}, {date: "2022-02-11", date_ts: 1644526800, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "d0q2", sub3: "", sub4: "", cost: 7744.36, sms_count: 2816, payout: 19125, net_margin: 11380.64}, {date: "2022-02-11", date_ts: 1644526800, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "d0q1", sub3: "mondata_check", sub4: "", cost: 3349.56, sms_count: 1218, payout: 36e3, net_margin: 32650.44}, {date: "2022-02-11", date_ts: 1644526800, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "d0q1", sub3: "data_check", sub4: "", cost: 5051.06, sms_count: 1836, payout: 15895, net_margin: 10843.94}, {date: "2022-02-11", date_ts: 1644526800, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "d0q3", sub3: "", sub4: "", cost: 7701.2, sms_count: 2800, payout: 7140, net_margin: -561.2}, {date: "2022-02-11", date_ts: 1644526800, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "d0q1", sub3: "kadata_check", sub4: "", cost: 2885.4, sms_count: 1049, payout: 0, net_margin: -2885.4}, {date: "2022-02-11", date_ts: 1644526800, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "d1q2", sub3: "bounce", sub4: "", cost: 2123.72, sms_count: 772, payout: 8268, net_margin: 6144.28}, {date: "2022-02-11", date_ts: 1644526800, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "ppp", sub2: "", sub3: "", sub4: "", cost: 0, sms_count: 0, payout: 45600, net_margin: 45600}, {date: "2022-02-11", date_ts: 1644526800, month: 2, week: 6, sub1: "sm", sub2: "bot", sub3: "vitrina", sub4: "", cost: 0, sms_count: 0, payout: 3055, net_margin: 3055}]}

console .log (convert (input .data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {map, prop, groupBy, applySpec, pipe, head, pluck, sum} = R</script>
```

We write a general-purpose function to group our values on first one key, and then inside each of those, on a second key, and then inside those, on a third, and so on;  at the innermost level, we call a custom function on the list of nested objects.  This is `restructure`; it recursively takes an array of keys and a function from a list of the nested objects to your output format, and it handles the traversal, applying that function to the innermost lists.

Here I use Ramda's `applySpec` to handle the conversion those innermost lists into your final format, passing it simple functions to handle the conversion of a list of values into a final value for various properties.  It's unclear what's supposed to happen with the `date` field.  I just choose the first one.  For the others, I simply sum the values of the inputs.

This does not handle empty lists of keys; it would be simple enough to do, checking first whether `k` is undefined and returning `fn (xs)` if it is, since the original list would then be the innermost one.

If you wanted more flexibility than just grouping on object properties, we could write a version that accepted an arbitrary key-generating function, perhaps something like this:

```js
const restructure = ([kf, ...kfs], innermost) => (xs) =>
  (kfs .length > 0 ? map (restructure (kfs, innermost)) : map (innermost)) (groupBy (kf) (xs))

const convert = restructure ([x => x. sub1, x => x.sub2 .toLowerCase ()], applySpec ({/* ... */}))
```